# iPhone/iPad app rejected because of subscription model?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

We intend to launch a *free* iPhone/iPad app on the AppStore.
The content will actually be accessible thanks to a subscription model (login/pwd authentication in iPhone app).

The subscription (about 100$ a month) is handled via a dedicated web server.
If used without subscription, this app will provide minimum value. 
Does anyone know if this kind of subscription model can be rejected by Apple ?

I know some apps follow this model, but I'd like to have your thought on this before starting in this direction.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: how do you intend to handle the payment? is it through apple's in-app purchase?

Comment: The payment would be handle by a dedicated "webshop". I think it is mandatory in our case, because this content is also available through a web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our app, previously approved, update was just rejected because we sell subscriptions through our website.  (We have been doing this for 15 years, without giving Apple 30% of our money.)  They are requiring that all subscriptions for iphone/ipad content go through in-app purchasing.  I guess we will be looking at building a browser based app instead.

Cheers,
Gerry

Comment: Thanks for reporting your experience.
Our app is still not on the app store. 
We already have a Web + iOS app, so the Web version could "replace" the native ones. I still don't know if the HTML 5 offline capabilities can "embed" a 20MB database...
Thanks anyway !

Comment: Something's just changed...
http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/02/15appstore.html

Comment: So, if I am reading this right, its still 30% if they use the apple method, but you can sell it yourself outside the app.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine AFAIK - As long your app is free and you put in the description that it requires a subscription to whichever service. When you submit the app, you'll need to hand over details to a test account to Apple so that they can test it, but other than that it's no hassle at all.

I know of an app which works just like that on the app store right now - Spotify for iPhone. It's a music playing app which streams music from the web - but you need a Spotify premium account. When you first open the app, you have to sign in, and if you don't have a premium account it just tells you that you're not allowed in!

- Javawag

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of apps which only work if I have an account somewhere, and some for which I have to pay for that account so, without knowing the specifics, there is nothing which immediately rules out your subscription model. There are even Apple apps, iDisk for example, which are useless if you don't have a $100 mobile me subscription.

If there are issues you can look at selling your subscription as an in app purchase (apple will take their 30% which should make them happy) or look at making the app more functional without the subscription.

Either way, when submitting for approval make sure to set up a sample account with a full subscription that the apple testers can use (there is space in the submission for including logins for this kind of thing).